# Facet title left alignment using facet_grid

Tags: ggplot2, facet-grid

I'm making a plot with facets where the length of facet titles vary quite a bit. I am trying to left-align the facet/strip title with hjust, but it seems like *hjust* adjust differently depending on length of each facet title. Ideally, I would like to align each facet title with the 0 on the axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(q = c(rep("q1", 16), rep("question mucher longer and longer and longer", 16)),
                   cat = c(rep(paste0("cat", 1:4), times = 8)),
                   p = rep(25, 32),
                   group = c(rep(paste0("group", 1:4), each = 4),
                   c(rep(paste0("group", 1:4), each = 4))))


ggplot(data = data,
       aes(x = group, y = p, fill = cat, label = p)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_stack(), width=0.6) +  
  facet_grid(col = vars(q)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3.5, color= "black") + 
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  theme_minimal(base_size=12) +
  theme(
    legend.position="bottom", 
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line( size=.1, color="gray"),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_line( size=.1, color="gray"),
    strip.text = element_text(face="bold", hjust=0.03)) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=c("0","25","50","75","100 %")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "gray23") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 100, color = "gray23") +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.margin=margin(0,0,0,0),
        legend.box.margin=margin(-10,0,0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `hjust = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the expansion of the y scale. Hence, the strip text box expands  over the 0 line. To fix your issue use `hjust=0` for the strip box text and remove the default expansion on the left (or bottom in your case) of the y scale. To show this clearer I added a red box around the strip text boxes:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  data = data,
  aes(x = group, y = p, fill = cat, label = p)
) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_stack(), width = 0.6) +
  facet_grid(col = vars(q)) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3.5, color = "black") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size = .1, color = "gray"),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(size = .1, color = "gray"),
    strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0, margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "pt")),
    strip.background.x = element_rect(color = "red")
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c("0", "25", "50", "75", "100 %"), expand = c(0, 0, .05, 0)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "gray23") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 100, color = "gray23") +
  theme(
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
    legend.box.margin = margin(-10, 0, 0, 0)
  )
```

[image]